# How Can I get two diffrents event with onclick?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this problem. When I click the first element p, the color change in red, and if I click the second element p after the first elment p the color will be green, but I want red. I would like have this efect: if i click the first elment p, it will be red, and after if I click the second element p, it will be red. I think my JavaScript code is wrong, what can I do for get this effect? 
Thank you all for your help

```js
var clicked = true;

function change(abba) {
  if (clicked) {
    abba.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    abba.style.color = "green";
  }
  clicked = !clicked;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
```

Comment: what will happen if i click any other `p` first ? i.e if i click fourth first and then first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `clicked` is a public variable, meaning it's the same for every element.
The easiest way of doing it would be checking the current color of the element

```js
function change(abba) {
  if (abba.style.color !== "red") {
    abba.style.color = "red";
  } else {
    abba.style.color = "green";
  }
}
```

```html
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle text color, you can check if current color is red, if it is, assign the color to green, set to red otherwise.

```js
function change(abba) {
  abba.style.color = abba.style.color === "red" ? "green" : "red";
}
```

```html
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
<p onclick="change(this)">HELLO WORLD</p>
```